# Better wording for "Among other [stuff]"

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, phrase-requests, uncountable-nouns

I have the following problem. I need to say

> Among other information, [the message] will contain information about the following...

I don't like the repetition of "information" here. I thought of

> Among other stuff, [the message] will contain information about the following...

I don't like the non-technical "stuff" here.

I also tried

> Among everything else, [the message] will contain information about the following...
>
> Among other things, [the message] will contain information about the following...

I don't like these either, perhaps because the message contains only information, so other things or everything else actually means other information, but using that leads to repetition (see first example).

There is a noun in Russian - прочее - which means other things, other stuff. So in Russian, I would be able to say Среди прочего [ = among other, ...]. Unfortunately, in English I can't say

> Among other, [the message] will contain information about the following...

When I think about it, it seems that part of the problem is that information is uncountable. If there was a countable noun instead, I'd write, for example,

> Among others, the following animals are kept in our zoo.

meaning

> Among other animals...

But with information it doesn't work this well. So can you help me express what I want to express (which I hopefully made clear)?.

Comment: Why do you assume you must start with that phrase or one like it? It's not the point of the sentence; it's just a qualification to warn that you're not being complete in the following list. This is better as a parenthetic aside instead of hogging the starting point of the sentence and arousing questions about whether it's important or not. Try _... will contain information about, among other things, the following ..._

Comment: Why is it necessary to use "among other [things]" at all?  If I say, "this box contains an egg" that does not preclude there being other things in it as well; and if that were the only thing pertinent to the present discussion, it would not be necessary to talk about what else may or may not be in the box.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I like your suggestion. Why don't you post an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: _Things_ often connotes material objects, but in the common expression 'amongst other things' it often refers to ideas or topics, and in 'things to do' activities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrase *[inter alia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter_alia#inter_alia)* (“among other things”), which has the handy abbreviation *i.a.*,   sometimes is useful.  For example:  “The message will detail troop strengths and deployments, i.a.”.  However, *inter alia* seems to me to be less applicable to living things.

Answer (score 3):

With a little bit of rephrasing, you can use *among*, by itself:

> Among the information that the message will contain, …
>
> Among the animals in our zoo, …

Or possibly, *including*:

> The message will contain information, including …
>
> We keep many animals in our zoo, including …

Comment: Or, even more simply, "This message will include information about..." Just replace _contain_ with _include_, as _include_ usually doesn't imply "exclusively."

Answer (score 0):

Typical phrasing of this concept is "among other things".

`things` is about the most generic word possible in English, so there are probably more arty ways to put this. But if you say "among other things" a native English reader will get the concept with a minimum of parsing effort.